# confusion over PHP with REST implementation

Tags: php, ajax, rest

I am creating an web app (php in backend), which will have mobile app. So I thought to go with REST API solution, which i used as client, most of the time.

Now I searched several framework and trying to use it. but i didn't found any framework to have basic which i want to understand with samples(or may be i am not able to get from it. i should not blame), I got confused on below points.

I am trying to achieve in this way.

mysite.com/**user/get/id** (get user data for id)

I didn't found in any example how to convert this into php code i.e.

***$user->get(id);***

So I just want to confirm, is this framework automatically parse it, or do i need to read url and get one by one value and redirect to appropriate function.

I need any good tutorial or help here to understand how to achieve it. How REST can be implemented in PHP application, another thing I am going to use ajax for communication which is very important.

I have used Flight, Slim, Tonic framework for this.

Comment: Why not learn some PHP basics first?

Comment: did i mentioned i didn't know basic of php?

Comment: it shows that :( $user->get($id) if you know how to write a class, method you would solve your problem

Comment: its pseudo code, not perfect, BTW I will correct it, My question was usage of any PHP based REST service framework, or do i need to use simple php to parse url and convert each parameter and url sections into appropriate action.

Comment: you will need to do your own implementation, but any framework will support the friendly url /user/get/id (:class/:method/:param)

Comment: It means Framework converts those url into exact action(based on url section and parameter).

Comment: yes, for an example /user/get/12 is actually something like `index.php?class=user&method=get&id=12` so you can get the id like $_GET['id']

Comment: url will become "http://mysite.com/index.php?class=user&method=get&id=12"? 
or 

"http://mysite.com/user/get/id" will be converted to "mysite.com/index.php?class=user&method=get&id=12 " by htaccess

Comment: thats correct, its done through htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for "front-controller example"

Answer (score -1):

This might be helpful for you
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: I am able to communicate with system, my question is for communication using REST framework